# SQL Server - Update with FROM and JOIN not considering all the rows that satisfies JOIN condition

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-update

So, I have two tables T1 and T2 where in T1 has Primary Key Column "A" with all Unique Values and T2 has Foreign Key "A" as shown below.

```
T1
---
A   ConditionMet 
1   0
2   0

T2
---
A    B     C
1    10    5
1    20    20
2    10    10
2    30    0
```

Now, I want to update "ConditionMet" column of T1 table to "1" whenever Value of Column B in T2 is equal to Value of Colum C (for one specific value in A). My update query is something like below

```
UPDATE t1
SET
t1.ConditionMet =
   (CASE WHEN t1.ConditionMet = 0 AND t2.B = T2.C THEN 1 END)
FROM
   T1 t1
INNER JOIN T2 t2
WHERE
   t1.A = t2.A
```

Here my problem is that it is not looping through all the rows of T2 but its going through first record with the value of "A". Suppose if we take value "1" in T1, it would only look at first row (1 10 5) but not at the second row (1 20 20) of T2. Please help me understand whats wrong with this query. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
UPDATE t1
SET
t1.ConditionMet = CASE WHEN t1.ConditionMet = 0 AND t2.B = T2.C 
                        THEN 1 
                   END      
FROM T1 t1
INNER JOIN T2 t2 ON t1.A = t2.A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM T2
                  WHERE t1.A = A
                   AND B <> C)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when it fits both conditions, you can't be assured the order of which update will occur last.  This should do what you need:

```
UPDATE t1
SET
    t1.ConditionMet = CASE WHEN T2.a IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM
   T1 t1
LEFT JOIN T2 t2
WHERE
   t1.A = t2.A
   and t2.B = t2.C
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are expecting a first, second or last result, but defining no order. Why should the row for A = 1 where B = 10 be first, and B = 20 be second? It is actually the update SQL Server does last that is the one that sticks, but even so, you can't fix your query with just an `ORDER BY`

You need to write a completely deterministic query, that is to say write a select that only returns 1 row per row being updated, and this can reliably be used as an update. I don't think I would go as far as Hugo Kornelis, who has called for [UPDATE...FROM](https://sqlserverfast.com/blog/hugo/2008/03/lets-deprecate-update-from/) to be deprecated, but you do need to understand it if you are to not be caught out by it.

So if you are looking to update rows in T1 where there is at least one row in T2 where B = C, then I would use:

```
SELECT  T1.A, T1.ConditionMet, NewConditionMet = ISNULL(T2.NewConditionMet, 0)
FROM    T1
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 NewConditionMet = 1
            FROM    T2
            WHERE   T2.A = T1.A
            AND     T2.B = T2.C
        ) AS T2;
```

For your sample data this will return

```
A   ConditionMet    NewConditionMet
1   0               1
2   0               1
```

All you then need to do is adapt your `SELECT` into an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE  T1
SET     ConditionMet = CASE WHEN T1.ConditionMet = 0 THEN ISNULL(T2.NewConditionMet, 0) END
FROM    T1
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 NewConditionMet = 1
            FROM    T2
            WHERE   T2.A = T1.A
            AND     T2.B = T2.C
        ) AS T2;
```

*N.B. This is a very rare occasion when I deem that it is okay to use `TOP` without `ORDER BY`, since I am only returning a constant value, 99% of the time is not okay to use `TOP` without `ORDER BY`*

---

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (A INT, ConditionMet BIT);
DECLARE @T2 TABLE (A INT, B INT, C INT);
INSERT @T1 VALUES (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 1);
INSERT @T2 VALUES (1, 10, 5), (1, 20, 20), (2, 10, 10), (2, 30, 0), (3, 0, 1), (4, 0, 0);

SELECT * FROM @T1;

UPDATE  T1
SET     ConditionMet = CASE WHEN T1.ConditionMet = 0 THEN ISNULL(T2.NewConditionMet, 0) END
FROM    @T1 AS T1
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 NewConditionMet = 1
            FROM    @T2 AS T2
            WHERE   T2.A = T1.A
            AND     T2.B = T2.C
        ) AS T2;

SELECT * FROM @T1;
```

Comment: May be I haven't my complete requirement. I have another column in T2 which says "Operator" which can be either "AND", "OR" or "NULL". So, for example, it might have a condition saying T2.B (10) = T2.C (5) "AND" T2.B (20) = T2.C (20). So, I can't skip looping through all the rows. I could achieve that using a "WHILE" loop but wanted to check with experts like you to see if I can avoid that. Thanks in Advance!!